# How can I ensure that 'fs.appendFileSync' never succeeds partially?

Tags: node.js, file-io

Up until now, my assumption has been that if `fs.appendFileSync` throws an exception, then it is guaranteed that the contents of the target file haven't changed one bit.

[The official documentation of this function](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options) doesn't refer to this issue (and to failure cases in general).

[The source code of this function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/bdc09c63e6ee9208ebab7e77ac513705263bbd9a/lib/fs.js#L1317) shows that it calls `fs.writeFileSync`, which in turn does this:

```
  try {
    while (length > 0) {
      const written = fs.writeSync(fd, data, offset, length, position);
      offset += written;
      length -= written;
      if (position !== null) {
        position += written;
      }
    }
  } finally {
    if (!isUserFd) fs.closeSync(fd);
  }
```

Can I infer from the above that `fs.appendFileSync` may throw an exception after partially changing the target file?

If yes, then are there any known tools or paradigms for tackling this rather-difficult-to-handle situation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, fs.appendFileSync doesn't support any form of transactions afaik. While i do not know any partical nodeJS-module for this use case, you could do it manually by

- duplicating the file
- appending to the duplicate tmp-file
- renaming/replacing the original file with the tmp file